# Unable to post data by AJAX to controller's Action in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

Here is my JavaScript to Post

`$.ajax(
            {
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "JSON",
             url: '${createLink(controller: "customer", action: "updateCheck")}',
             data: 'this is parameter',
             success: function(answer){
                console.log(answer);
               }
            }
            )`

Here is my controler:

`def updateCheck(){
        def parameters = params
        print(parameters)
        log.error(parameters)
    }`

I want to post data to server by AJAX call from client. but I am unable to do that getting following error

`POST http://loscalhost.hasToUseThis:9091/qbx-web/customer/$%7BcreateLink(controller:%20%22customer%22,%20action:%20%22updateCheck%22)%7D 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you're enclosing `'${createLink(controller: "customer", action: "updateCheck")}'` in 'hard' quotes. If you use double quotes instead, the `${create...}` will be evaluated properly.

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "JSON", 
    url: "${createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'updateCheck')}", 
    data: 'this is parameter', 
    success: function(answer) { console.log(answer); } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: '${createLink(controller: "customer", action: "updateCheck")}',
    data: {params:'this is params'},
    success: function(answer){
        console.log(answer);
    }
});
```